# Dropbox Selective Sync Config File

Tags: dropbox

I have dual boot - Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04. I use Dropbox on both systems. I use the same folder using ubuntu fstab.

Which file in Windows AppData contains Selective Sync config? I want to symlink it to Ubuntu. Is it possible?